# androidx.lifecycle.LiveDataReactiveStreams class not found after version 2.6.0

Tags: android, rx-java, android-livedata

I just started to play with [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata).
I followed the official Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#declaring_dependencies) to import the different artifacts. Everything was fine until I needed to convert an `Observable` to `LiveData`. But `LiveDataReactiveStreams` was not found.
Eventually I decreased version number and  when I reached **2.5.1** I got surprised it's finally worked.

Did I do something wrong?
Or is the issue on Google's side?

I couldn't find any reported issue related this. But I really don't know what could I possible do differently...

I tried import it manually. Then I used `android.arch.lifecycle.LiveDataReactiveStreams`. That worked But than I should've been stick with it and change all the `androidx` to `android.arch` what isn't a real solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [document of 2.6](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.6.0), they have changed `LiveDataReactiveStreams` to a Kotlin conversion. So there are no longer `LiveDataReactiveStreams` that contain only static methods (Kotlin can call it as an extension function). Read the document for more details

[image]

Comment: That's right. I have to read changelog  way more carefully. Thank you!